# Downloading video & audio segment simultaneously with youtube-dl and ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

For an online streaming video that I would like to download I have two m3u8 files.

One for the video itself with segment-0.ts to segment-250.ts:

```
#EXTINF:6.000000,
segment-0.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
segment-1.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
segment-2.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
segment-3.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
segment-4.ts
```

and another m3u8 for the audio segments:

```
#EXTINF:6.016000,
segment-0.aac
#EXTINF:6.016000,
segment-1.aac
#EXTINF:6.016000,
segment-2.aac
#EXTINF:6.016000,
segment-3.aac
#EXTINF:6.016000,
```

So, I use youtube-dl and ffmpeg to download the both m3u8 separately then merge them to get the final mp4 (audio+video).

Is there a way to merge the files or use a combined command in the Terminal to automatically download both and merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg can process multiple inputs:

```
ffmpeg -i <first> -i <second> output.mp4
```

Just place both URLs returned from youtube-dl:

```
youtube-dl -g <my-first-url>
youtube-dl -g <my-second-url>
```

If you are using a unix (linux/MacOS) system you can do both steps in one command:

```
ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -g <my-first-url>) -i $(youtube-dl -g <my-second-url>) output.mp4
```

Comment: Keep in mind  video codec argument is necessary otherwise stream can be reencoded in lower quality