# How do I combine PyTube audio and video streams in a Flask app and let the user download as one file without storing on the web server?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pytube

I'm building a YouTube downloader as a side project in Flask. It allows users to input a url and download the video without storing anything on the server I'm hosting on

Lower quality videos can be sent to the user easily as they from PyTube as one file. I use the code below:

```
import os
import flask
from flask import redirect, url_for, session, send_file
import requests

import pytube
from pytube import YouTube
from io import BytesIO

@app.route('/pull_videos', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def pull_videos(): 
  buffer=BytesIO()
  yt_test=YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNNPgIfK2YE')
  video = yt_test.streams.get_by_itag(251)

  video.stream_to_buffer(buffer)
  buffer.seek(0)

  return send_file(buffer, as_attachment=True, download_name="Test video")
```

However, I struggle when trying to pull in higher quality videos as they come in as separate audio and videos streams (see documentation here: https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/streams.html#)

I am trying to use ffmpeg to combine the two and then send to the user, but the code below isn't working as expected and throws an error:

Code:

```
import os
import flask
from flask import redirect, url_for, session, send_file
import requests
import ffmpeg

import pytube
from pytube import YouTube
from io import BytesIO

@app.route('/pull_videos', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def pull_videos(): 
  buffer=BytesIO()
  
  video = yt_test.streams.get_by_itag(137)
  input_video = ffmpeg.input(video)
  
  audio = yt_test.streams.get_by_itag(137)
  input_audio = ffmpeg.input(audio)
  
  combined = ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1)
  combined.stream_to_buffer(buffer)
  buffer.seek(0)

  return send_file(buffer, as_attachment=True, download_name="Test video")
```

**Error:**    AttributeError: 'FilterableStream' object has no attribute 'stream_to_buffer'

How could I combine these audio and video streams from PyTube into one file for the user to download without storing on the server?

Comment: You need to study `ffmpeg-python` API more closely, but nonetheless your current approach will be a major uphill battle IMO. Without getting into why, see if you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187306/4516027). You can pipe ffmpeg's stdout to wherever you wish to send to. BTW, MP4 will be a no-go file format as it's not compatible with a pipe (I think MKV will work).

Comment: I'll try that when I next have a chance to work on this, thanks - when you say study the API more closely, do you mean here: https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/

I spent some time trying to get it to work using various things from this page, but couldn't find a working solution

Comment: My actual suggestion for you regarding running FFmpeg from Python is: don't use `ffmpeg-python` and just run `subprocess.Popen` with the exact FFmpeg cli arguments you need. This will result in a cleaner code and easier to get help from those of us generic ffmpeg users. (My original comment was in case you're bound to using the `ffmpeg-python` package.)

Comment: I'm definitely not bound to using ffmpeg-python, I have flexibility to take whatever approach is best. I'll try the subprocess.Popen route you're suggesting and spend time trying it myself (likely won't have time to do it until this weekend due to work) and hope it's okay if I revert with additional questions. Thanks.